# Do any of the Windows system applications use WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows

Context: I am looking for examples of popular applications that use WPF for their UI.

With Windows 8 and Windows 10, certain parts of the OS got a new 'look-and-feel', for example:

- The system settings dialog
- The taskbar and the start menu
- The calculator app
- The task manager

**Do those or any other Windows system applications use WPF for their UI?**

This question already provides a list of existing applications that use WPF: [What real world WPF applications are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837/what-real-world-wpf-applications-are-out-there). However, I would like to know if there are any builtin Windows system applications that use WPF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What real world WPF applications are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837/what-real-world-wpf-applications-are-out-there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those applications use WPF. Instead they use UWP, which was inspired by WPF, but is quite a different framework underneath.

There are WPF applications in many default Windows installations, though. For example, the PowerShell ISE is one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Snooping](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/87261) them to find out - It's not been updated for several years but I tried it on a splinter new 4.6 app I'm developing and it's detecting it and works fine. Whatever it can detect is certainly a WPF app - the inverse is not true however.
That being said it did not detect calculator or task manager for me.